# Equivalent of node_type_get_types()

Tags: nodes, 8

Can somebody help mi with use of node_type_get_types() in Drupal 8?

#### Code in Drupal 7

```
function node_type_get_types() {
  return _node_types_build()->types;
}
```

#### Code in Drupal 8

```
function node_type_get_types() {
  return NodeType::loadMultiple();
}
```

This was my code in Drupal 7. How to now use node_type_get_types in Drupal 8?

```
$options = array();
  foreach (node_type_get_types() as $type) {
    $options[$type->type] = $type->type;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node types are (config) entities, so they have the same methods available as others. Specifically, relevant for you, all entities have id() and label() methods:

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType;

$options = array();
foreach (NodeType::loadMultiple() as $type) {
  $options[$type->id()] = $type->label();
}
```

Those methods are defined on `\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface`, you can use them anything that's an entity and that includes almost every type of content and configurable thing, nodes, users, roles, views, image styles, ...

Comment: Thank you a lot. You save me. I am writening 3 last function and hope that module would be finish.  In drupal 7 I use return system_settings_form($form); So in Drupal 8 I use \Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase or system_config_form()